# Irreducible gaussian integers with prime norm in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, gaussian-integers

I need to prove this

> Prove that a Gauss integer $z = a +ib$, with $a \ne 0, b \ne 0$ is
> irreducible if and only if $a^2 + b^2$ is a prime element in ℤ.

I've already proved that $N(z)$ prime implies, $z$ irreducible element:

If $N(z)$ is a prime, then $z$ is irreducible since if we write it as $z=xy$, it follows that $N(z) = N(x)N(y)$, thus either $x$ or $y$ is a unit.

I'm not able to prove the converse: if z is irreducible then $N(z)$ is prime
, which is no generally true, but it is for this particular case with $a \ne 0, b \ne 0$.

**Note** The unique factorization theorem was not still introduce so far in the course and I'd like not to resort on it.

Comment: Knowing that $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a HIR, we also have [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367917/is-it-true-that-abi-is-prime-in-mathbbzi-if-and-only-if-a2b2-is).